# Is "enter a dance animation with" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is "enter a dance animation with" idiomatic?
It's a very new expression, because it's mostly used for video games, so I was wondering if it was idiomatic? I am not sure, but maybe there's a better way of saying it, because it sounds odd.

For example:

> My male character entered a dance animation with the female character.

Comment: I have no idea what a *dance animation* could possibly be. *Animation* is a series of drawn or generated still images that are put together in sequence so as to appear to be live action. Unless it's something like a musical version of the movie [*Tron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron), entering a dance animation doesn't seem possible. Do you mean *a dance* ***competition***?

Comment: You can be [animated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/animated) - full of interest and energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an idiomatic expression and never has been. When interperetting this sentence, the reader will take it literally. In the context of videogames, `animation` usually means a set collection of movements. And yes, it does sound odd.

Comment: How would you reword it?